# To find Straight line perpendicular to the given line equation and area with the co-ordinate axes

Tags: geometry

If a straight line perpendicular to $2x - 3y + 7= 0$ forms a triangle with the co-ordinate axes whose area is $3$ sq.units, then what is the equation of the straight line?

Answer (score 1):

The slope of that perpendicular line should be $\frac {-3}{2} $ and thus the equation of that line will be $$y = -1.5x +c \Rightarrow 2y+3x =2c =k$$ where $k$ is some constant.

The triangle thus formed will have vertices of $A\,(0,0)\,; B\,(k/3,0)\,;C\,(0,k/2) $. Hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

The original line 
$$
2x - 3y + 7 = 0  \iff (2,-3) (x,y)^T = -7
$$
has a normal vector
$$
n = (2,-3)^T
$$
So a perpendicular line has the general equation
$$
(3,2) \cdot (x,y)^T = a
$$
for some constant $a$, which we can write as
$$
y = -(3/2) x + a/2
$$
Then the triangle has the vertices $(0,0)^T$, $(0,a/2)^T$ and $(a/3, 0)^T$

The area of the triangle is 
$$
A = (1/2) (a/2)(a/3) = a^2 / 12 = 3
$$
so we get $a = \sqrt{36} = 6$.

This gives
$$
3x + 2y = 6
$$
as equation.